# jQuery bookmarklet for selectors

Tags: jquery, bookmarklet

It should work like this:

1. Fire a bookmarklet
2. Select the first element by clicking
3. Select the second element
4. It outputs a series of jQuery calls which would allow selecting the second element given a reference to a first element (i.e. using relative positions of the two elements in a DOM tree).

Is there such a bookmarklet (or browser extension)? If no may be you could give me a clue about how to write one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [jQuerify](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet). It loads jQuery as a bookmarklet, after which you can interact with the DOM. The same sort of stuff exists in [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Just add a listener to the body to listen for the first mousedown/click on an element and store it in some data structure (like an array). You could probably chain events together to try to get it where you want.

Depending what you're doing, you could do some spatial detection using the coordinates of the element too.